# router-outlet is appending rather than replacing Angular 6.0.3

Tags: angular

When I use `<a routerLink="/settings">settings</a>` and component code is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

it is not navigating `/routing` to settings component , rather it is opening in same page.

I am using Angular 6.0.3 version.

Comment: Can you please create a StackBlitz (or something similar) that reproduces the problem? Thank you

Comment: If you're navigating to `routerLink="/settings"` , you will go to the **Settings** page. This is the expected behaviour.  You must use  `routerLink="/routing"`

Comment: settings page is opening on bottom of current page. i dont want in bottom. it needs to replace the page. for example if i click the login button, home page needs to open but here it is opening in bottom of the login button.